# Ada HashMap in HashMap

Tags: hashmap, ada

I don't know, if this is called currying, but I want to have a HashMap(String, Long, Short, String);

The GNAT compiler complains:

```
main.adb:20:13: warning: possible infinite recursion
main.adb:20:13: warning: Storage_Error may be raised at run time
main.adb:24:13: warning: possible infinite recursion
main.adb:24:13: warning: Storage_Error may be raised at run time
```

What is the correct way to write the "=" function here?

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps;
with Ada.Strings.Hash;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   subtype Short is Short_Integer;
   subtype Long is Long_Integer;

   function Hash (X : String) return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type is
      (Ada.Strings.Hash (X));

   function Hash (X : Short) return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type is
      (Ada.Containers.Hash_Type'Mod (X));

   function Hash (X : Long) return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type is
      (Ada.Containers.Hash_Type'Mod (X));

   package Short_String_Map is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps (Short, String, Hash, "=");
   function "=" (Left, Right : Short_String_Map.Map) return Boolean is
      (Left = Right);

   package Long_Short_Map is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps (Long, Short_String_Map.Map, Hash, "=");
   function "=" (Left, Right : Long_Short_Map.Map) return Boolean is
      (Left = Right);

   package String_Long_Map is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Hashed_Maps (String, Long_Short_Map.Map, Hash, "=");
begin
   --  Map(String, Long, Short, String);
   null;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
function "=" (Left, Right : Short_String_Map.Map) return Boolean is
    (Left = Right);
```

write

```
function "=" (Left, Right : Short_String_Map.Map) return Boolean is
    (Short_String_Map."=" (Left, Right));
```

or, even better (I think):

```
function "=" (Left, Right : Short_String_Map.Map) return Boolean 
    renames Short_String_Map."=";
```

The problem is that the way you wrote it, the `=` in `Left = Right` refers to the `"="` that you just defined on the line above, according to the visibility rules.  Naturally this means you've just defined an infinitely recursive function.  To use the `"="` defined in `Short_String_Map` instead, you have to use a syntax like `Short_String_Map."="(Left,Right)` to make it explicit which `"="` you're referring to.